# Ограничение ввода в textInput PHP

Tags: php, yii2, ввод

Есть поле ввода на php:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'MAX_TIME')->textInput() ?>
```

Как мне сделать ограничение в нем, что бы пользователь мог вводить только числа от 0 до 10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это Yii2 как я понимаю, то вот так:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'MAX_TIME')->input('number', ['min' => 0, 'max' => 10]) ?>
```

Comment: Да, Yii2, спасибо большое, помогло.

Comment: а можете подсказать еще с одним вопросом?
Работаю с базой данных Oracle на PHP на фреймворке Yii2.
В БД Oracle не существует понятий "булеан" и поэтому для поля пришлось задать тип integer.
При добавлении данных в БД на PHP есть такая вот строка:

    <?= $form->field($model, 'RANDOM')->checkbox() ?>

Если CheckBox не активировать, то в БД записывается 0. Если поставить галочку, то при добавлении в БД выскакивает ошибка. Как сделать так, что бы в БД записывалась 1 (Единичка), если я активировал CheckBox?

Comment: C Oracle не работал